# copy media files from one folder to another, but rename the files

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I want to have a function in my game manager that "clones" a game.  So far I have all the cloning working except cloning the game media.

I want the media to clone/copy like this:

> basePath + gameId + mediaFile

So a simple example would look like this:

```
--- original game
c:\inetpub\wwwroot\spac_rpg\MediaFiles\12\33d43636-275b-4b92-8778-cf591829103e.png
c:\inetpub\wwwroot\spac_rpg\MediaFiles\12\57ea0ad8-c69a-45e7-951e-d0325aa404ab.mov
```

becomes

```
--- new clone of the game (notice the different gameIds and the different GUID Ids for the media)
c:\inetpub\wwwroot\spac_rpg\MediaFiles\13\4427a554-b6a7-457a-b5ff-7c7cb7aee5bb.png
c:\inetpub\wwwroot\spac_rpg\MediaFiles\13\e9371c5d-eb47-4014-8380-204f7aff44fb.mov
```

So far I have this, which isn't much, but I'm kinda stuck on where to go next:

```
' copy each media file to new folder with new name

' new and old media file IDs
Dim newMediaId As Guid
Dim oldMediaId As Guid
Dim oldGameId As Int

' base path for game media
Dim basePath = "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\spac_rpg\MediaFiles\"

' new media folder
Dim newMediaFolder = Directory.CreateDirectory(basePath & newGameId)

' XXX ds is a dataset that is returned from the database with the old and new mediaIDs
For Each dr As DataRow In ds.Tables(0).Rows

    oldMediaId = dr("oldMediaID")
    newMediaId = dr("newMediaID")

    Dim oldFile = (basePath & oldGameId & "\" & oldMediaId)
    Dim clonedFile = (basePath & newGameId & "\" & newMediaId)

Next
```

Or maybe I'm trying to break this down to much and there's a much easier way of copying?

I just need to make sure that the new folder with the new GameId is created and that each new media file is cloned with the newMediaId that is returned from the database call.

Thanks!

Comment: I think you are looking for a review. It looks fine, I don't see anything wrong except you could use System.IO.Path but isn't necessary. When everything is done and working, you could post on codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: you can use File.copy to copy files between directories.

Comment: @preciousbetine won't that keep the filename the same too?  I'd like to have different GUIDs

Comment: @the_lotus well I can't figure out how to do the actual copy...like copy the file but have the new file with a new filename

Comment: you can change the file name from the File.copy command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [System.IO.File.​Copy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.copy?view=netframework-4.7.2) can do the copy for you. It takes the source file and destination file (which can be different) as parameters).

```
System.IO.File.​Copy(oldFile, clonedFile)
```

Comment: How do I get the file extension of the old file?  Thanks!

Comment: @SkyeBoniwell [Path.​Get​Extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getextension?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_IO_Path_GetExtension_System_String_) ? If you want to file the path without knowing it in advance, that would be a different question.